# Looking for a simple equivalent to a formattable textarea

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, textarea

I have created a little dsl for querying our company database.  I am now trying to create a web front end.  I began using textareas to allow users to enter their queries, but recently discovered that you can't format pieces of texts within textareas (which I would do to highlight errors in query text, etc) -- tags don't work within a textarea.

We have standardized on Google Chrome, so what I'd like is a widget that:

1. looks like a text area
2. can be resized (like textareas in Chrome)
3. allows formattting of substrings within itself by use of tags and classes (e.g., a substring)

what I don't want:

1. toolbars/buttons, etc
2. a complex api in order to simply do the above.

I've looked at [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com), but can't figure out how to get the entire text of the textarea, search for a substring, then wrap that substring in a tag.  (I've done this with a regular textarea and javascript, so if it's similar, great.)

Any guidance, ideas, etc, greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to check the "contenteditable" attribute if things should be really simple.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, after working with `contenteditable` for quite some time, I have to say there isn't a single thing that's simple about it. Yes, the idea behind is is simple, and someday it should be simple, but the browser inconsistencies make it nearly impossible to work with for anything that's structured (esp. like this).

Comment: Right, I just suggested it due to the point of standardization on Google Chrome by OP, and it's developing fast.

Comment: Oh, right, good call. My bad!

Comment: "contenteditable" doesn't cause the resize thingy to appear on the div, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm wrong, see my comments below to Jukka K. Korpela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could use a `div` (or another) element with the `contenteditable` attribute and some styling. You can then get the element content with markup in the `innerHTML` property and the as plain text in the `textContent` property. Simple example:

```
<div contenteditable style=
  "width: 20em; height: 10em; overflow: auto; border: solid gray 1px" 
  id=c>foo <i>bar</i></div>
<button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('c').innerHTML)">show</button>
```

Comment: Note about this: if you want to control the HTML in any way (or the editor look), I would suggest against `contenteditable`. I worked with it for quite some time before I came across CodeMirror, and the browser inconsistencies were an absolute pain. You have to go through several hacks just to get the basic usage to *appear* the same (the output, not the HTML, which is a totally different story).

Comment: I tried that, but as far as I can tell, there's no way to make the div resizable.  I tried the JQueryUI "resizable" widget, but that has a major problem: if you keep creating new lines, it creates a new div for each line, and eventually your new lines appear beneath the lower boundary of the resizable widget.

Comment: @davej, doesn’t `resize: both` in CSS for the `div` work for you?

Comment: @Jukka, unfortunately, no, it doesn't.  I just tried it, and when I check it in "Inspect element", it shows that the div does indeed have the css rule "resize: both", but I'm not getting the the little resize handle in the lower right corner. Thanks for the input, tho!

Comment: @davej, that’s odd, works fine for me, on Chrome 17 (Win 7), with the markup I gave and just this declaration added. BTW, it also works on Firefox.

Comment: @Jukka: you're right!  something in my style must have been off.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor may be your choice.
It's easy to configure and use its API:
http://ckeditor.com/
http://docs.cksource.com/

You can create your own toolbar or use none.

Comment: Took a little bit, but got it to work exactly as I'd hoped (embedded tags in the textarea text).

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) (and on [GitHub](https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror2)). It has a ton of formatting options already available, and sounds like exactly what you're looking for (a syntax highlighter). It's extremely customizable (I've been able to make this thing bend over backwards for me) and works across a ton of browsers.

You could start out with the [MySQL Mode](http://codemirror.net/mode/mysql/index.html), and customize it as necessary (I'm assuming some sort of SQL when you say query, but other modes could work instead, if I'm mistaken).

To have the editor automatically resize, add the following to your CSS:

```
.CodeMirror-scroll {
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%
}
```

Comment: I'm trying CodeMirror out now, and it looks very good.  I'm trying to figure out how I can "manually" (i.e., via javascript) highlight the code that I want to highlight, based on what my own parser tells me is an error (based in turn on my custom dsl which doesn't really look like any existing language). Looks like "marktext" should do it.  I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: @davej, for a project I'm working on, I'm using a *very* limited (and slightly different) version of Markdown. So, I started with the Markdown mode, and changed it from there as needed, first by removing unneeded parts, and then changing/adding other parts to be valid. If you are writing a mode from scratch, I recommend reading the [manual](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#config). Else, I'd suggest finding a mode that is the most similar and doing what I did with the Markdown mode (as each mode has different functions it uses internally) and see how it turns out. Best of luck!